# Parsing rules for / (Reduce) in APL in the presence of n-wise reduce?

Tags: apl

I thought the parse rules of APL were straightforward: on seeing a term `⍺ f ⍵`, have the function `f` receive arguments `⍺, ⍵`. Indeed, for the reduction `/` operator in APL, we can think of:

```
+/(1 2 3 4) ⍝ REDUCE(+, (1 2 3))
10
```

However, this logic is thrown out the window in the case of:

```
2+/(1 2 3 4) ⍝ REDUCE(2, +, (1, 2, 3)) ?
(3 5 7)
```

That is, it seems that the parse of this needs to look *two behind* in the intermediate parse tree --- one behind to retrieve the operator `+`, and two behind to retreive the number `2`.

This significantly complicates my mental model of how to read and parse APL expressions --- am I missing something here? Alternatively, if this is actually how this works, are there other APL operators that "look behind" more than 1 sub-expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an introduction to APL, the simple rules about functions and arrays are adequate, but once you throw operators (and especially dyadic operators) into the mix, thins get a bit more complicated. While the functions/arrays rules still apply, a function can now be *derived* using one or more operators. In fact, you can end up looking far to the left to find out where a function "begins".

Consider e.g. the function `*∘*∘*∘*`, *f(a,b)=a<sup>e<sup>e<sup>e<sup>b</sup></sup></sup></sup>*, in the context `2*∘*∘*∘*3`:

`3` this is our array

`*` maybe we'll apply this function monadically to `3`, but it depends…

`∘` nope: this is a dyadic operator which "grabs" the `*` on its right to derive a new function

`*` maybe this is `∘`'s left operand, but it depends…

`∘` nope: this is a dyadic operator which "grabs" the `*` on its right to derive a new function

`*` maybe this is `∘`'s left operand, but it depends…

etc.

This is in fact how I parse APL in my head. However, a more precise overall approach is using a binding strengths table as per the [documentation](http://help.dyalog.com/latest/#Language/Introduction/Binding%20Strength.htm) and the [model implementation](http://dfns.dyalog.com/n_parse.htm)